# C# How can I read a file content passing relative path in DiagnosticAnalyzer

Tags: c#

I have a custom analyzer.
In the analyzer .csproj file I have:

```
<ItemGroup>
        <Content Include="../../../docs/MyFile.txt">
            <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
        </Content>
    </ItemGroup>
```

How can I read this file in DiagnosticAnalyzer class?

```
private void Analyze(
        SyntaxNodeAnalysisContext context,
        ClassDeclarationSyntax classDeclaration,
        ITypeSymbol type
    )
    {
       
        var termsFile = new AnalyzerAdditionalFile("./MyFile.txt");
        
        var documentationFileLines = new HashSet<string>();

        var fileText = termsFile.GetText(context.CancellationToken);
        foreach (var line in fileText!.Lines)
        {
            documentationFileLines.Add(line.ToString());
        }

        ...
        }
    }

    public override void Initialize(AnalysisContext context)
    {
        base.Initialize(context);
        context.HandleClassDeclaration(Analyze);
    }
```

```
public sealed class AnalyzerAdditionalFile : AdditionalText
{
    public AnalyzerAdditionalFile(string path)
    {
        Path = path;
    }

    public override string Path { get; }

    public override SourceText GetText(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        return SourceText.From(File.ReadAllText(Path));
    }
}
```

I've tried to add this as additional file but it always was not included in SyntaxNodeAnalysisContext.options.AdditionalFiles.

Comment: Looks like this works:

```

<ItemGroup>
        <EmbeddedResource Include="../../../docs/MyFile.txt" />
    </ItemGroup>
```


Then in code:
```
var a = Assembly.GetCallingAssembly();
        var resA = a!.GetManifestResourceStream("ProjectName.MyFile.txt");

        using var reader = new StreamReader(resAss!, Encoding.UTF8);
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this works:

```
<ItemGroup>
        <EmbeddedResource Include="../../../docs/MyFile.txt" />
    </ItemGroup>
```

Then in code:

```
var a = Assembly.GetCallingAssembly();
        var resA = a!.GetManifestResourceStream("ProjectName.MyFile.txt");

        using var reader = new StreamReader(resAss!, Encoding.UTF8);
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**